# an htop-like tool to display disk activity in linux

Tags: linux, command-line, io

I am looking for a Linux command-line tool that would report the disk IO activity. Something similar to `htop` would be really cool.  Has someone heard of something like that?

Comment: Note that you can also do this in `htop`. `Setup >> Select Columns` and choose your combination of `RBYTES`, `WBYTES`, `IO_READ_RATE`, `IO_WRITE_RATE`, and `IO_RATE`. Original answer here http://serverfault.com/a/25034

Comment: htop can do it please see <https://serverfault.com/questions/25032/linux-disk-io-load-breakdown-by-filesystem-path-and-or-process> second answer

Answer (score 185, accepted):

You could use [iotop](http://guichaz.free.fr/iotop/). It doesn't rely on a kernel patch. It Works with stock Ubuntu kernel

There is a package for it in the Ubuntu repos. You can install it using

```
sudo apt-get install iotop
```

[image: iotop]

Comment: +1 Love being able to see the process that is killing my I/O.

Comment: A python version of this is here, but requires root: http://guichaz.free.fr/iotop/

Comment: Use `yum install iotop` for Centos

Comment: @HaydenThring `iotop` also needs needs to be used as root because... it's the same package. Exactly the same ouput on the program and the `--version` flag as well. Did worked perfectly.

Answer (score 69):

[nmon](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-analyze_aix/) shows a nice display of disk activity per device.  It is available for linux.

```
? Disk I/O ?????(/proc/diskstats)????????all data is Kbytes per second??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????ĳ
?DiskName Busy  Read WriteKB|0          |25         |50          |75       100|                                                      ?
?sda        0%    0.0  127.9|>                                                |                                                      ?
?sda1       1%    0.0  127.9|>                                                |                                                      ?
?sda2       0%    0.0    0.0|>                                                |                                                      ?
?sda5       0%    0.0    0.0|>                                                |                                                      ?
?sdb       61%  385.6 9708.7|WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR>                 |                                                      ?
?sdb1      61%  385.6 9708.7|WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR>                 |                                                      ?
?sdc       52%  353.6 9686.7|WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR   >                  |                                                      ?
?sdc1      53%  353.6 9686.7|WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR   >                  |                                                      ?
?sdd       56%  359.6 9800.6|WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW>                    |                                                      ?
?sdd1      56%  359.6 9800.6|WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW>                    |                                                      ?
?sde       57%  371.6 9574.9|WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR>                   |                                                      ?
?sde1      57%  371.6 9574.9|WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR>                   |                                                      ?
?sdf       53%  371.6 9740.7|WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR    >                 |                                                      ?
?sdf1      53%  371.6 9740.7|WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR    >                 |                                                      ?
?md0        0% 1726.0 2093.6|>disk busy not available                         |                                                      ?
??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
```

Comment: I tried this, and while the refresh was slow, the graphing of MB/s is too small when dealing with SSD drives (it goes to a scale of 0, 25, 50, 75, and 100 TB/s).  I ended up using iotop as its default refresh is fast and actually shows the process killing the I/O.  Still a +1 for an option though.

Answer (score 15):

It is not htop-like, but you could use [atop](http://www.atcomputing.nl/Tools/atop/). <del>However, to display disk activity per process, it needs a kernel patch (available from the site).</del> These kernel patches are now [obsoleted](http://www.atoptool.nl/downloadpatch.php), only to show per-process network activity an optional module is provided.

Comment: this one is shipped with fedora 18 and is working fine for me. Perhaps these patches are already upstream. There is a netatop optional module for per process network activity if one wants that.

Answer (score 5):

Use `collectl` which has extensive process I/O monitoring including monitoring threads.

Be warned that there are I/O counters for I/O being written to cache and I/O going to disk.  `collectl` reports them separately.  If you're not careful you can misinterpret the data. See http://collectl.sourceforge.net/Process.html

Of course, it shows a lot more than just process stats because you'd want one tool to provide everything rather than a bunch of different one that displays everything in different formats, right?